# Monotonic constraints in regression model with interaction

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, constraint

I'm trying to figure out what constraints I need to use to have monotonicity (both on $x$ and $z$) on the regression model with interaction. My model is:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|x,z]= \beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2z+\beta_3xz,$$

thus, to get an increasing function in x and z, I need the derivatives wrt x and z to be positive:
$$\beta_1+\beta_3z\ge0 \quad\text{ and } \quad\beta_2+\beta_3x\ge0$$

If x and z are both positive, I conclude: $\beta_i \ge 0, \quad i= 1,\ldots,3$.

Since I would estimate the model with standardised $x$ and $z$, I also can have negative values. How can I solve the system in that case?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need these constraints? Imposing such constraints based on pre-conceptions about response-surface shapes can be unwise.

Comment: How do you derive this conclusion?  If $x$ and $z$ can be arbitrarily large, then you cannot have $\beta_3$ be negative.  Note, too, that this surface (*qua* function of $(x,z)$) is not a plane: it's a piece of a hyperboloid.

Comment: I need them because is a dose-response relation and I need to constraint the surface to be monotonic increasing.

Comment: Obviously you won't be able to guarantee that your conditions are satisfied unless $\beta_3 = 0$, as it's possible to have, for example, a single arbitrarily large $z_i$ and arbitrarily small (negative) $z_i$.

Comment: If it's dose-response, do you really want to allow negative values for $x$ and $z$?

Comment: Yes, the dependent and the independent variables are on very different scales, that's why I would like to standardise the independent variables. But it's not strictly necessary, I know.

Comment: You're right @whuber, thanks. I can't consider the derivative without x and z just because they are positive. I'm going to correct my post!

Comment: Also, dose-response curves often display [hormesis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormesis) in practice, non-monotonic shapes. Don't restrict your analysis unnecessarily; that might not be consistent with the underlying reality.

Comment: Thanks @EdM for your comment. I know the hormesis process, but from previous studies, I can assess this is not my case. This is not the final structure of my model. I have a piecewise polynomial structure on my risk factors and its flexibility results in a decreasing function at high levels of the predictors. I've just asked the first 'step' of my problem because I don't want the solution. I prefer to understand the mechanism in this simple case to be able to extend the procedure to my final model.

Answer (score 1):

These types of constraints are linear in the variables, and a linear regression with linear constraints become a linearly constrained quadratic programming (QP) problem. Most regression solvers do not allow such constraints, but you can formulate it yourself and use an open source QP solver such as cvxopt (python).

For the relationship between QP and linearly constrained linear regression problems, see [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/HOA/JAMDS/8/2131.pdf).